# How to delete the hidden cropped elements from a pdf from the command line?

Tags: linux, pdf, crop

How can I delete the hidden cropped elements from a pdf from command line? I've tried many solutions to crop an element on a pdf page based on the coordinates, but the resulting pdf is of the same size and the extra elements are just masked instead of removed. I've found [this solution](http://www.proficiografik.com/2009/11/17/acrobat-9-when-the-crop-tool-is-not-cropping-and-how-to-fix-it.html), but I'm looking for a command line tool.

Comment: I found a much better solution using pdfE from Apago. It gets the works done and much faster too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only method I'm aware of that can do this *while preserving all PDF objects inside the CropBox* working on the commandline (Windows, Linux, MacOSX) is a commercial/payware software by [**callassoftware**](http://www.callassoftware.com/).

If this is acceptable to you, please indicate that in a comment, and I'll update the answer with some more details.

Otherwise another method is to convert the (cropped) PDF page(s) to images (f.e. to a TIFF with the help of Ghostscript), and then re-convert the image back to PDF. All previous PDF objects will be gone, and the only (graphical) "object" that's there now will be an image that's embedded on the PDF page(s).

If this is acceptable to you, indicate this in a comment, and I'll update the answer with some more details.

Comment: callassoftware is definitely something that we could use. Can I get some additional details on this one?

Comment: The main issue I have with the ghostscript approach is that, I can't select the text from the resulting image. Main requirement is to be able to select the text when cropping the element.

Comment: @vivek85: You could 'heal' that defect (can't select text from resulting image) by applying an OCR (optical character recognition) tool to the PDF afterwards. This will embed the text as a 'hidden' one (not directly visible, but selectable; what is visible is still only the image).

Comment: Any pointers on the callassoftware tool? I downloaded the CLI version and I couldn't find any straight-forward way to do the cropping.

Comment: @vivek85: The callassoftware tool per se doesn't do much without a *'profile'* (.kfpx filename suffix). However, that profile you need to create with the GUI/Desktop version of the software. The GUI you'll only get for Windows and Mac OS X. But after creating the profile, on Win/Mac, you can *export* it and use it with the Linux commandline version. So shortest explanation is: *create a profile to remove unwanted elements on Win or Mac, export it as a file *.kfpx, and use a CLI on Linux that calls that profile...*

Comment: @pipitas: The tiff conversion using gs didn't really do anything on the size front. It actually made the size bigger. To get a reasonable quality I had to use -r600x600 which increased the size to 15 MB which is too much for my use. Thanks for the callassoftware tip. I will play with it.

Comment: @vivek85: I didn't have in mind and didn't consider your intention to decrease the file size too. My impression was you wanted to remove objects in order to prevent them from being evaluated at all (to prevent leakage of confidential information).

Comment: @vivek85: Be aware of the fact that page objects whose position lays halfway inside, halfway outside your cropbox cannot be removed halfway only: you'll have to make a hard decision -- keep fully or remove fully.